# Could not find `Cargo.toml` when building a dependent crate from GitHub

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use the [rust-mosquitto library](https://github.com/kteza1/rust-mosquitto). My current `Cargo.toml` is:

```
[package]
name = "HomeDaemon"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["RTR <k.teza1@gmail.com>"]

[dependencies.mosquitto]
git = "https://github.com/kteza1/rust-mosquitto"
```

When I run `cargo build`, following error is reported:

```
Could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/Users/ravitejareddy/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-8203e77dcf072bf7/rust-mosquitto`
```

The actual download in `~/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-8203e77dcf072bf7/master` shows that `Cargo.toml` is present.

There is an extra `rust-mosquitto` in the path above, is that a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from your [`Cargo.toml` in examples/ticktock](https://github.com/kteza1/rust-mosquitto/blob/master/examples/ticktock/Cargo.toml):

```
[dependencies.mosquitto]
version = "*"
path = "../../../rust-mosquitto"
```

When downloading your project from git, all the subdirectories are scanned for more `Cargo.toml` files. If you run `RUST_LOG=trace cargo build -v`, you see what's happening:

```
TRACE:cargo::ops::cargo_read_manifest: looking for root package: /Users/shep/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-77eb7033f32b19c9/master, source_id=https://github.com/kteza1/rust-mosquitto#7e08a291
TRACE:cargo::ops::cargo_read_manifest: looking for child package: /Users/shep/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-77eb7033f32b19c9/master
TRACE:cargo::ops::cargo_read_manifest: read_package; path=/Users/shep/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-77eb7033f32b19c9/master/Cargo.toml; source-id=https://github.com/kteza1/rust-mosquitto#7e08a291
TRACE:cargo::ops::cargo_read_manifest: looking for child package: /Users/shep/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-77eb7033f32b19c9/master/.git
TRACE:cargo::ops::cargo_read_manifest: not processing /Users/shep/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-77eb7033f32b19c9/master/.git
TRACE:cargo::ops::cargo_read_manifest: looking for child package: /Users/shep/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-77eb7033f32b19c9/master/examples
TRACE:cargo::ops::cargo_read_manifest: looking for child package: /Users/shep/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-77eb7033f32b19c9/master/examples/c-mosquitto
TRACE:cargo::ops::cargo_read_manifest: looking for child package: /Users/shep/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-77eb7033f32b19c9/master/examples/ticktock
TRACE:cargo::ops::cargo_read_manifest: read_package; path=/Users/shep/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-77eb7033f32b19c9/master/examples/ticktock/Cargo.toml; source-id=https://github.com/kteza1/rust-mosquitto#7e08a291
DEBUG:cargo: handle_error; err=CliError { error: ChainedError { error: Unable to update https://github.com/kteza1/rust-mosquitto, cause: Could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/Users/shep/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust-mosquitto-77eb7033f32b19c9/rust-mosquitto` }, unknown: false, exit_code: 101 }
```

Cargo then tries to ensure that the nested `Cargo.toml` can have all of the dependencies satisfied.

Comment: @tez: Because you go up *three* directories, when there are only *two* in the repository.  You're effectively requiring that your repository *always* be checked out with the name `rust-mosquitto` and *nothing else*.

Comment: Ok. The folder structure is different while downloading from git where Cargo.toml resides inside branch name. 'master' in this case.

Answer (score 8):

This does not specifically answer the question that @tez asked, but I encountered the same error with a slightly different root culprit. I was writing some simple code in vim, so I created a simple main.rs file. When I `cargo run` it, it was spitting out the same error:

> error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/Users/yvonmanzi/Documents/Rust` or any parent directory

The surprising thing, without the hindsight, of course, was that `rustc main.rs` was creating a binary executable as expected while `cargo run` wasn't. It turns out I had created all my rust packages(aka projects) up to that point using `cargo new project-name --bin` as shown [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/creating-a-new-project.html), thus by default including `Cargo.lock`, `Cargo.toml`, and `src` folder. Hopefully, it is clear by now that mine was just a simple rookie mistake; I simply, quite literally, didn't have `Cargo.toml` in my project folder. So, dear fellow rooky league Rustacean, if you get the same error, create your project with `cargo new project-name --bin` command.

Comment: If this contains a separate question and answer you can post it as a separate question and then self answer it. If very relevant when you have enough reputation to post comments you could even leave a comment on this question referencing the related question.

Comment: I think a correction is needed; both your "mistake" and "recommendations" presently show to use, `cargo new project-name --bin` to create a project.

Answer (score 2):

On git hub, I found the answer for this problem.  There was a small couple of line script I created, chmodded it, then ran it.  It worked perfectly!  Here is the script:

```
cargo install --list | 
awk '/^\w/ { print $1 }' | 
while read x; do cargo install "$x"; done
```

I didn't change a thing.  Make sure you run it from `$HOME/.cargo`
One of the best, shortest answers I have ever found!

Answer (score 2):

run this on terminal ->

```
sudo find / -name Cargo.toml
```

this will find the path of the file

then run ->

```
cd <the path of the file (ofc excluding the file itself)>
```

now cargo is working for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem I figured was that I wasn't running the command in the correct directory.

1. After running the "cargo new <proj_name>"
2. you need to cd into your <proj_name> directory/folder and
3. then execute "cargo run" command.

Note: I tried running "cargo run <proj_name>" to see if it could run from outside the folder, but failed.
I believe the cargo is looking in current directory for pom file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in executing the command in the wrong directory.
Following the "**`cargo new project_name --bin`**" command,
it is essential to navigate or change the directory ("**`cd`**") into the "**project_name**" directory before running the subsequent command, which is triggering the error.

Answer (score -1):

It worked after i executed those *.sh under program/scripts ( then cargo build-bp again )